# Deploying Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, dreamhost

I have a question about deploying a Rails application. I know the information exists else where, but my issue is that I can't place it cohesively together. Currently I'm on Dreamhost and would like instructions on how to deploy my app there. I feel like I should be using Capistrano in some fashion but I honestly am pretty lost. Any suggestions on deploying easily or a better host that is around the same price point (less than $10 a month).

Comment: Capistrano has a nice [tutorial](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-From-The-Beginning). Without a specific question, I don't think you will get a helpful answer here.

Comment: You may want to check out Heroku (http://heroku.com) since their deployment process is *extremely* simple without having to use Capistrano.  Not only that, but it's free for small-scale hosting.

Answer (score 3):

> Any suggestions on deploying easily or a better host that is around the same price point (less than $10 a month).

Have you heard of Heroku yet? You can run a single dyno instance (one running instance of your application) for free, including access to a shared Postgres database service. It's extremely popular among rubyists for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [this](http://peepcode.com/products/phusion-passenger) screencast from peepcode for details about hosting your app using capistrano. It is about installing phusion-passenger but they also explain how you can host your application on 'Dreamhost'